# how to edit variable path's using canvas and javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am not sure how to make the "mercury" variable orbit around the sun instead of the Earth. I am trying to add to MDN's canvas tutorial.I am ultimately trying to figure out how to add new planets with orbits around the sun(which stay's static in the canvas).Below is the JS:

```
var sun = new Image();
var moon = new Image();
var earth = new Image();
var mercury = new Image();//added variable

function init(){
  sun.src = 'assets/starsWeb.png';
  moon.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/1443/Canvas_moon.png';
  earth.src = 'assets/earthWeb1.png';
  mercury.src = 'assets/mercury.png'
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

}

function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500); // clear canvas

  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)';
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,153,255,0.4)';
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(150,150);



  // Earth
  var time = new Date();
  ctx.rotate(((2*Math.PI)/60)*time.getSeconds() + ((2*Math.PI)/60000)*time.getMilliseconds());
  ctx.translate(105,0);
  ctx.fillRect(0,-12,50,24); // Shadow
  ctx.drawImage(earth,-12,-12);

  // Moon
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate(((2*Math.PI)/6)*time.getSeconds() + ((2*Math.PI)/6000)*time.getMilliseconds());
  ctx.translate(0,28.5);
  ctx.drawImage(moon,-3.5,-3.5);
  ctx.restore();

  //mercury -ADDED CODE I WANT THIS TO ORBIT THE SUN BUT IT ONLY ORBITS THE EARTH LIKE IT IS THE MOON

   var mercTime = new Date();
   ctx.rotate(((2*Math.PI)/60)*mercTime.getSeconds() + ((2*Math.PI)/60000)*mercTime.getMilliseconds());
   ctx.translate(20,0);
   ctx.drawImage(mercury,-9,-9);


  ctx.restore();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(150,150,105,0,Math.PI*2,false); // Earth orbit
  //ctx.arc(50,50,105,0, Math.PI*2, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.drawImage(sun,0,0,300,300);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}


init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Scale, Rotate, Translate multiply existing transform.

You want Mercury's rotation and translation applied to the suns position not the moons.

Move the code to rotate and draw Mercury just above the Earth code. Then wrap  the Mercury code with a save and restore so you can keep the Sun's current transform for rendering the Earth, Moon.

```
   ctx.save();
   var mercTime = new Date();
   ctx.rotate(((2*Math.PI)/60)*mercTime.getSeconds() + ((2*Math.PI)/60000)*mercTime.getMilliseconds());
   ctx.translate(20,0);
   ctx.drawImage(mercury,-9,-9);
   ctx.restore();
```

The functions `ctx.rotate`, `ctx.translate`, `ctx scale`, and `ctx.transform` apply the transform to the existing transformation. Thus if you rotate 1 deg then do another 1 deg, you have rotated the rotated, giving a total of 2 deg. Same applies for the others, `ctx.translate(10,10)` then `ctx.translate(10,10)` is the same as `ctx.translate(20,20)`

Using save and restore allows you to return to a previous transformation. Or you can use `ctx.setTransform` which overwrites the existing transform with a new one.

Comment: Makes allot more sense now. Thanks!